# How to create a drop down menu with a table?

Tags: javascript, html-table, hidden

I'm trying to create a drop down menu similar to what you would see with a 'ul'.

The difference being I want to do it with a table.

When the page loads I have td's with their 'display' attribute equal to 'none'. This hides the td for me.

The problem is in the javascript below.

```
function displayMenuOptions() {
            var _1 = document.getElementById("1");
            var _2 = document.getElementById("2");
            var _3 = document.getElementById("3");

            _1.setAttribute("style", "display : block");
            _2.setAttribute("style", "display : block"); 
            _3.setAttribute("style", "display : block"); 
}
```

This function is being fired by a mouseover on another td with an 'a' child element.

This javascript is not displaying the td's I originally had hidden.

Ideas?

Comment: You were both correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[IDs cannot begin with numbe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)rs -- change them to be `cell_1, cell_2, cell_3, etc.` and everything should just work.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**SEE:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2

Answer (score 1):

```
_1.style.display = "block";
```